# How to diff two boost::property_tree?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

Please consider two 'boost::property_tree'-s.

ptree1:

```
{
    "node1" : 1,
    "node_that_only_appears_in_this_one" : 2,
    "node3" :
    {
        "nested1" : 3,
        "nested2"
        {
            "double_nested1" : 5,
            "double_nested2" : "foo"
        }
    }
}
```

ptree2:

```
{
    "node1" : 1,
    "node3" :
    {
        "nested1" : 3,
        "nested_that_only_appears_in_this_one" : 5,
        "nested2"
        {
            "double_nested1" : 5,
            "double_nested2" : "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write a general function that I can call like so:

```
ptree_whats_changed(ptree1, ptree2);
```

such that, in this particular case, the return value is another property tree that looks like this:

```
{
    "node3" :
    {
        "nested_that_only_appears_in_this_one" : 5,
        "nested2"
        {
            "double_nested2" : "foo"
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if nodes are removed when going from ptree1 to ptree2 - it is enough simply to see the ones that are modified or have been added.

My understanding is that the property_tree stores everything as a flat list (with . to separate the paths) so that this might be easier than it seems, without necessarily having to recurse.

Answer (score 6):

The current version of Boost.Property (1.55) does not provide direct support for [mathematical relations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/property_tree/appendices.html#property_tree.appendices.future_development), such as a difference.  However, one can write a function to iterate over the tree and invoke a user provided function with both the node's full path and the node itself.  As each iteration will provide the node's full path, algorithms can easily [access data](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/accessing.html) and construct a result with `get()`, `put()`, or `add()`.

For example, here is a function that can iterate over a tree:

```cpp
/// @brief Walk a Boost.PropertyTree tree, invoking the binary function with
///        the full path and the current node.
template <typename Tree, typename Function>
void for_each(
    const Tree& tree, 
    Function fn,
    const typename Tree::path_type& parent_path = typename Tree::path_type())
{ 
  using path_type = typename Tree::path_type;
  for (auto&& value_pair: tree)
  {
    auto current_path = parent_path / path_type(value_pair.first);
    fn(current_path, value_pair.second);
    for_each(value_pair.second, fn, current_path);
  }
}
```

And this algorithm uses iteration to construct the difference:

```cpp
/// @brief Return tree with elements in @ref s but not in @ref t.
template <typename Tree>
Tree tree_difference(const Tree& s, const Tree& t)
{
  using data_type = typename Tree::data_type;
  Tree result;
  // Iterate 's', adding to the result when either a node in
  // 't' is not present in 's' or the node's values differ.
  for_each(s, 
    [&](const typename Tree::path_type& path, const Tree& node)
    {
      auto value = t.template get_optional<data_type>(path);
      if (!value || (value.get() != node.data()))
        result.add(path, node.data());
    });
  return result;
}
```

---

Here is a [complete example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08ed882e4118661f) that demonstrates performing a difference between two trees.  I have also added other operations, such as union, intersection, and symmetrical difference to demonstrate extensibility in the event that `tree_difference()` does not provide the exact desired result.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace tree_ops {

/// @brief Walk a Boost.PropertyTree tree, invoking the binary function with
///        the full path and the current node.
template <typename Tree, typename Function>
void for_each(
    const Tree& tree, 
    Function fn,
    const typename Tree::path_type& parent_path = typename Tree::path_type())
{ 
  using path_type = typename Tree::path_type;
  for (auto&& value_pair: tree)
  {
    auto current_path = parent_path / path_type(value_pair.first);
    fn(current_path, value_pair.second);
    for_each(value_pair.second, fn, current_path);
  }
}

/// @brief Return tree with elements in @ref s but not in @ref t.
template <typename Tree>
Tree tree_difference(const Tree& s, const Tree& t)
{
  using data_type = typename Tree::data_type;
  Tree result;
  // Iterate 's', adding to the result when either a node in
  // 't' is not present in 's' or the node's values differ.
  for_each(s, 
    [&](const typename Tree::path_type& path, const Tree& node)
    {
      auto value = t.template get_optional<data_type>(path);
      if (!value || (value.get() != node.data()))
        result.add(path, node.data());
    });
  return result;
}

/// @brief Return tree with elements from both @ref s and @ref t.
template <typename Tree>
Tree tree_union(const Tree& s, const Tree& t)
{
  // The result will always contain all values in @ref s.
  Tree result = s;
  // Iterate 't', add values to the result only if the node is
  // either not in 's' or the values are different.
  for_each(t, 
    [&](const typename Tree::path_type& path, const Tree& node)
    {
      auto child = s.get_child_optional(path);
      if (!child || (child->data() != node.data()))
        result.add(path, node.data());
    });
  return result;
}

/// @brief Return tree with elements common to @ref s and @ref t.
template <typename Tree>
Tree tree_intersection(const Tree& s, const Tree& t)
{
  using data_type = typename Tree::data_type;
  Tree result;
  // Iterate 's', adding common elements found in 't' that have the same
  // value.
  for_each(s,
    [&](const typename Tree::path_type& path, const Tree& node)
    {
      auto value = t.template get_optional<data_type>(path);
      if (value && (value.get() == node.data()))
        result.add(path, node.data());
    });
  return result;
}

/// @brief Return tree with elements in either @ref s or @ref t, but not
///        both.
template <typename Tree>
Tree tree_symmetric_difference(const Tree& s, const Tree& t)
{
  return tree_difference(tree_union(s, t), tree_intersection(s, t));
}

} // namespace tree_ops

// Expose mathematical tree operations with operators.

/// @brief Return tree with elements in @ref lhs but not in @ref rhs.
boost::property_tree::ptree operator-(
    const boost::property_tree::ptree& lhs,
    const boost::property_tree::ptree& rhs)
{
  return tree_ops::tree_difference(lhs, rhs);
}

/// @brief Return tree with elements in both @ref lhs and @ref rhs.
boost::property_tree::ptree operator|(
    const boost::property_tree::ptree& lhs,
    const boost::property_tree::ptree& rhs)
{
  return tree_ops::tree_union(lhs, rhs);
}

/// @brief Return tree with elements common to @ref lhs and @ref rhs.
boost::property_tree::ptree operator&(
    const boost::property_tree::ptree& lhs,
    const boost::property_tree::ptree& rhs)
{
  return tree_ops::tree_intersection(lhs, rhs);
}

/// @brief Return tree with elements in either @ref lhs or @ref rhs, but not
///        both.
boost::property_tree::ptree operator^(
    const boost::property_tree::ptree& lhs,
    const boost::property_tree::ptree& rhs)
{
  return tree_ops::tree_symmetric_difference(lhs, rhs);
}

int main()
{
  std::istringstream json1_stream {
      "{"
      "  \"node1\" : 1,"
      "  \"node_that_only_appears_in_this_one\" : 2,"
      "  \"node3\" :"
      "  {"
      "    \"nested1\" : 3,"
      "    \"nested2\" :"
      "    {"
      "      \"double_nested1\" : 5,"
      "      \"double_nested2\" : \"foo\""
      "    }"
      "  }"
      "}"};

  std::istringstream json2_stream {
      "{"
      "  \"node1\" : 1,"
      "  \"node3\" :"
      "  {"
      "    \"nested1\" : 3,"
      "    \"nested_that_only_appears_in_this_one\" : 5,"
      "    \"nested2\" :"
      "    {"
      "      \"double_nested1\" : 5,"
      "      \"double_nested2\" : \"bar\""
      "    }"
      "  }"
      "}"};

  boost::property_tree::ptree tree1, tree2;
  read_json(json1_stream, tree1);
  read_json(json2_stream, tree2);

  std::cout << "difference in tree2 and tree1:\n";
  write_json(std::cout, tree2 - tree1);

  std::cout << "union of tree1 and tree2:\n";
  write_json(std::cout, tree1 | tree2);

  std::cout << "intersection of tree1 and tree2:\n";
  write_json(std::cout, tree1 & tree2);

  std::cout << "symmetric difference of tree1 and tree2:\n";
  write_json(std::cout, tree1 ^ tree2);
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
difference in tree2 and tree1:
{
    "node3":
    {
        "nested_that_only_appears_in_this_one": "5",
        "nested2":
        {
            "double_nested2": "bar"
        }
    }
}
union of tree1 and tree2:
{
    "node1": "1",
    "node_that_only_appears_in_this_one": "2",
    "node3":
    {
        "nested1": "3",
        "nested2":
        {
            "double_nested1": "5",
            "double_nested2": "foo",
            "double_nested2": "bar"
        },
        "nested_that_only_appears_in_this_one": "5"
    }
}
intersection of tree1 and tree2:
{
    "node1": "1",
    "node3":
    {
        "nested1": "3",
        "nested2":
        {
            "double_nested1": "5"
        }
    }
}
symmetric difference of tree1 and tree2:
{
    "node_that_only_appears_in_this_one": "2",
    "node3":
    {
        "nested2":
        {
            "double_nested2": "foo",
            "double_nested2": "bar"
        },
        "nested_that_only_appears_in_this_one": "5"
    }
}
```

Note: As [`get_child()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp101691848-bb) is being used directly or indirectly, if a tree has duplicate keys, then the results may not be deterministic.

> Depending on the path, the result at each level may not be completely determinate, i.e. if the same key appears multiple times, which child is chosen is not specified. This can lead to the path not being resolved even though there is a descendant with this path. Example:
>
> ```
> *   a -> b -> c
> *     -> b
> *
> ```
>
> The path "a.b.c" will succeed if the resolution of "b" chooses the first such node, but fail if it chooses the second.

A more complete algorithm implementation would likely need to iterate over both trees to completion, populating an intermediate data structure that supports duplicate keys.  Operations would then be performed on the intermediate data structure, and a tree would be constructed from the results.

Comment: This is so nice, thank you! Is boost 1.64 any different or does it lack differencing too?

Comment: So this actually fails for `<User UserID="2"><Name>ADMIN</Name</User><User UserID="3"><Name>NOTADMIN</Name></User>`, reporting NOTADMIN as the change in the resulting diff, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This approach won't work with arrays because ptree represents them with an empty string as key. When using the path, the empty string is ignored.